# Frequently misused tags - list here

Tags: discussion, tagging

Apropos of [this conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/conversation/tag-scope-and-especially-schema), I'd like to start up a list of frequently mis-applied tags (e.g. [schema](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schema) being used for data modelling questions that should be tagged [database-design](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-design)).  Could we please add a list of tags in the answers, along with the ways they're mis-applied and what to re-tag as in the various cases.

I'll start with:

- [schema](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schema) used for data modelling questions.  These should be tagged [database-design](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-design).  Questions about schemas (namespace/ownership of tables and other DB objects in various DBMS platforms) should retain the [schema](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schema) tag.

As we add answers I'll make up a link farm in the question that points out to the more detailed discussions in the answers, where the actual use of the tag can be discussed and written up in detail.

Comment: I can see where schema might get mis-used. I remember learning in college about creating a schema for our database before writing the SQL (DDL) for it. In this case it is a synonym for database-design. If you think of it like a schema within a database within a database instance, etc., then no it is not a schema. And actually....if you take a peek at the wiki for the schema tag....it does actually have the definition that I would relate to database-design. So we either need to change our wiki entry or add a different tag for the other definition of schema.

Answer (score 6):

SQL is frequently misused to mean SQL-Server.  I don't think anything but manual cleanup can be done about this.

Comment: +1 - or tagging `sql` and `server`